# RedhawkSDR 1.10 forced load balancing

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running Redhawk 1.10 on CentOS 6.7. The waveform is using the ArbitraryRateResampler component which is flushing the data quite frequently and I am wondering if there is a way to better distribute the processing load. I have a 4 core processor and the Redhawk GPP's options do not seem to allow custom core assignments. Are there any other options that Redhawk 1.10 might provide?

Answer (score 0):

Stuart C:

While the cpu affinity functionality that you are asking about is not well documented, there are excellent examples provided on Github at https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/blob/master/src/testing/tests/test_05_AffinityDeployments.py.  There you will find a unittest script and the associated nodes and waveforms.  All of the XML file references in that example script are relative to src/testing/sdr.

You will find examples of:

```
- cpu affinity for a node 
- cpu affinity for a waveform
```

Please review the test code to determine how to correctly configure cpu affinity for your system performance needs.  This is a REDHAWK 2.0 framework feature only.